# Trying to install with WUBI, got error about missing file

Tags: windows, wubi, 14.10

I've just mounted the Ubuntu 64-bit 14.10 ISO to my thumb drive, and I'm trying to install from Windows 8.1 using WUBI. Everything seemed to be going fine until I was thrown an error about a missing file. I don't really know what to do about it, as I don't really understand the problem. Here is the log:

```
12-19 00:02 INFO   root: === wubi 14.10 rev289 ===
12-19 00:02 DEBUG  root: Logfile is c:\users\tierney\appdata\local\temp\wubi-14.10-rev289.log
12-19 00:02 DEBUG  root: sys.argv = ['main.pyo', '--exefile="E:\\wubi.exe"']
12-19 00:02 DEBUG  CommonBackend: data_dir=C:\Users\Tierney\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl7609.tmp\data
12-19 00:02 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: 7z=C:\Users\Tierney\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl7609.tmp\bin\7z.exe
12-19 00:02 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: startup_folder=C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup
12-19 00:02 DEBUG  CommonBackend: Fetching basic info...
12-19 00:02 DEBUG  CommonBackend: original_exe=E:\wubi.exe
12-19 00:02 DEBUG  CommonBackend: platform=win32
12-19 00:02 DEBUG  CommonBackend: osname=nt
12-19 00:02 DEBUG  CommonBackend: language=en_US
12-19 00:02 DEBUG  CommonBackend: encoding=cp1252
12-19 00:02 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: arch=amd64
12-19 00:02 DEBUG  CommonBackend: Parsing isolist=C:\Users\Tierney\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl7609.tmp\data\isolist.ini
12-19 00:02 DEBUG  CommonBackend:   Adding distro Edubuntu-i386
12-19 00:02 DEBUG  CommonBackend:   Adding distro Kubuntu-amd64
12-19 00:02 DEBUG  CommonBackend:   Adding distro Mythbuntu-i386
12-19 00:02 DEBUG  CommonBackend:   Adding distro Edubuntu-amd64
12-19 00:02 DEBUG  CommonBackend:   Adding distro Ubuntu Studio-amd64
12-19 00:02 DEBUG  CommonBackend:   Adding distro Ubuntu-amd64
12-19 00:02 DEBUG  CommonBackend:   Adding distro Lubuntu-i386
12-19 00:02 DEBUG  CommonBackend:   Adding distro Ubuntu-i386
12-19 00:02 DEBUG  CommonBackend:   Adding distro Mythbuntu-amd64
12-19 00:02 DEBUG  CommonBackend:   Adding distro Kubuntu-i386
12-19 00:02 DEBUG  CommonBackend:   Adding distro Ubuntu Studio-i386
12-19 00:02 DEBUG  CommonBackend:   Adding distro Lubuntu-amd64
12-19 00:02 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: Fetching host info...
12-19 00:02 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: registry_key=Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Wubi
12-19 00:02 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: windows version=vista
12-19 00:02 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: windows_version2=Windows 8.1
12-19 00:02 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: windows_sp=None
12-19 00:02 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: windows_build=9600
12-19 00:02 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: gmt=-5
12-19 00:02 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: country=US
12-19 00:02 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: timezone=America/New_York
12-19 00:02 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: windows_username=Tierney
12-19 00:02 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: user_full_name=Tierney
12-19 00:02 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: user_directory=C:\Users\Tierney
12-19 00:02 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: windows_language_code=1033
12-19 00:02 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: windows_language=English
12-19 00:02 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: processor_name=Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-3217U CPU @ 1.80GHz
12-19 00:02 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: bootloader=vista
12-19 00:02 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: system_drive=Drive(C: hd 228725.339844 mb free ntfs)
12-19 00:02 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: drive=Drive(C: hd 228725.339844 mb free ntfs)
12-19 00:02 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: drive=Drive(D: cd 0.0 mb free )
12-19 00:02 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: drive=Drive(E: removable 2687.60546875 mb free ntfs)
12-19 00:02 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: drive=Drive(Z: hd 99888.1953125 mb free ntfs)
12-19 00:02 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: EFI boot = True
12-19 00:02 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: uninstaller_path=C:\ubuntu\uninstall-wubi.exe
12-19 00:02 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: previous_target_dir=C:\ubuntu
12-19 00:02 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: previous_distro_name=Ubuntu
12-19 00:02 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: keyboard_id=67699721
12-19 00:02 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: keyboard_layout=us
12-19 00:02 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: keyboard_variant=
12-19 00:02 DEBUG  CommonBackend: python locale=('en_US', 'cp1252')
12-19 00:02 DEBUG  CommonBackend: locale=en_US.UTF-8
12-19 00:02 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: total_memory_mb=3981.68359375
12-19 00:02 DEBUG  CommonBackend: Searching ISOs on USB devices
12-19 00:02 DEBUG  CommonBackend: Searching for local CDs
12-19 00:02 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether C:\Users\Tierney\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl7609.tmp is a valid Ubuntu CD
12-19 00:02 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain C:\Users\Tierney\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl7609.tmp\casper\filesystem.squashfs
12-19 00:02 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether C:\Users\Tierney\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl7609.tmp is a valid Ubuntu CD
12-19 00:02 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain C:\Users\Tierney\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl7609.tmp\casper\filesystem.squashfs
12-19 00:02 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether C:\Users\Tierney\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl7609.tmp is a valid Kubuntu CD
12-19 00:02 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain C:\Users\Tierney\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl7609.tmp\casper\filesystem.squashfs
12-19 00:02 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether C:\Users\Tierney\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl7609.tmp is a valid Kubuntu CD
12-19 00:02 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain C:\Users\Tierney\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl7609.tmp\casper\filesystem.squashfs
12-19 00:02 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether C:\Users\Tierney\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl7609.tmp is a valid Mythbuntu CD
12-19 00:02 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain C:\Users\Tierney\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl7609.tmp\casper\filesystem.squashfs
12-19 00:02 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether C:\Users\Tierney\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl7609.tmp is a valid Mythbuntu CD
12-19 00:02 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain C:\Users\Tierney\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl7609.tmp\casper\filesystem.squashfs
12-19 00:02 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether C:\Users\Tierney\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl7609.tmp is a valid Edubuntu CD
12-19 00:02 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain C:\Users\Tierney\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl7609.tmp\casper\filesystem.squashfs
12-19 00:02 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether C:\Users\Tierney\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl7609.tmp is a valid Edubuntu CD
12-19 00:02 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain C:\Users\Tierney\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl7609.tmp\casper\filesystem.squashfs
12-19 00:02 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether C:\Users\Tierney\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl7609.tmp is a valid Lubuntu CD
12-19 00:02 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain C:\Users\Tierney\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl7609.tmp\casper\filesystem.squashfs
12-19 00:02 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether C:\Users\Tierney\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl7609.tmp is a valid Lubuntu CD
12-19 00:02 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain C:\Users\Tierney\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl7609.tmp\casper\filesystem.squashfs
12-19 00:02 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether C:\Users\Tierney\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl7609.tmp is a valid Ubuntu Studio CD
12-19 00:02 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain C:\Users\Tierney\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl7609.tmp\casper\filesystem.squashfs
12-19 00:02 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether C:\Users\Tierney\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl7609.tmp is a valid Ubuntu Studio CD
12-19 00:02 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain C:\Users\Tierney\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl7609.tmp\casper\filesystem.squashfs
12-19 00:02 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether D:\ is a valid Ubuntu CD
12-19 00:02 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain D:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
12-19 00:02 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether D:\ is a valid Ubuntu CD
12-19 00:02 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain D:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
12-19 00:02 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether D:\ is a valid Kubuntu CD
12-19 00:02 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain D:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
12-19 00:02 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether D:\ is a valid Kubuntu CD
12-19 00:02 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain D:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
12-19 00:02 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether D:\ is a valid Mythbuntu CD
12-19 00:02 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain D:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
12-19 00:02 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether D:\ is a valid Mythbuntu CD
12-19 00:02 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain D:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
12-19 00:02 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether D:\ is a valid Edubuntu CD
12-19 00:02 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain D:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
12-19 00:02 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether D:\ is a valid Edubuntu CD
12-19 00:02 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain D:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
12-19 00:02 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether D:\ is a valid Lubuntu CD
12-19 00:02 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain D:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
12-19 00:02 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether D:\ is a valid Lubuntu CD
12-19 00:02 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain D:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
12-19 00:02 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether D:\ is a valid Ubuntu Studio CD
12-19 00:02 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain D:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
12-19 00:02 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether D:\ is a valid Ubuntu Studio CD
12-19 00:02 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain D:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
12-19 00:02 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether E:\ is a valid Ubuntu CD
12-19 00:02 DEBUG  Distro:   parsing info from str=Ubuntu 14.10 "Utopic Unicorn" - Release amd64 (20141022.1)
12-19 00:02 DEBUG  Distro:   parsed info={'name': 'Ubuntu', 'subversion': 'Release', 'version': '14.10', 'build': '20141022.1', 'codename': 'Utopic Unicorn', 'arch': 'amd64'}
12-19 00:02 INFO   Distro: Found a valid CD for Ubuntu: E:\
12-19 00:02 INFO   root: Running the CD menu...
12-19 00:02 DEBUG  WindowsFrontend: __init__...
12-19 00:02 DEBUG  WindowsFrontend: on_init...
12-19 00:02 INFO   WinuiPage: appname=wubi, localedir=C:\Users\Tierney\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl7609.tmp\translations, languages=['en_US', 'en']
12-19 00:02 INFO   WinuiPage: appname=wubi, localedir=C:\Users\Tierney\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl7609.tmp\translations, languages=['en_US', 'en']
12-19 00:02 INFO   root: CD menu finished
12-19 00:02 INFO   root: Already installed, running the uninstaller...
12-19 00:02 INFO   root: Running the uninstaller...
12-19 00:02 INFO   CommonBackend: Launching previous uninestaller C:\ubuntu\uninstall-wubi.exe
12-19 00:02 DEBUG  root: application.quit
12-19 00:02 DEBUG  WindowsFrontend: frontend.quit
12-19 00:02 DEBUG  WindowsFrontend: frontend.on_quit
12-19 00:02 DEBUG  root: application.on_quit
12-19 00:02 INFO   root: sys.exit
12-19 00:03 INFO   root: === wubi 14.10 rev289 ===
12-19 00:03 DEBUG  root: Logfile is c:\users\tierney\appdata\local\temp\wubi-14.10-rev289.log
12-19 00:03 DEBUG  root: sys.argv = ['main.pyo', '--exefile="E:\\wubi.exe"']
12-19 00:03 DEBUG  CommonBackend: data_dir=C:\Users\Tierney\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl2FE3.tmp\data
12-19 00:03 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: 7z=C:\Users\Tierney\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl2FE3.tmp\bin\7z.exe
12-19 00:03 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: startup_folder=C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup
12-19 00:03 DEBUG  CommonBackend: Fetching basic info...
12-19 00:03 DEBUG  CommonBackend: original_exe=E:\wubi.exe
12-19 00:03 DEBUG  CommonBackend: platform=win32
12-19 00:03 DEBUG  CommonBackend: osname=nt
12-19 00:03 DEBUG  CommonBackend: language=en_US
12-19 00:03 DEBUG  CommonBackend: encoding=cp1252
12-19 00:03 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: arch=amd64
12-19 00:03 DEBUG  CommonBackend: Parsing isolist=C:\Users\Tierney\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl2FE3.tmp\data\isolist.ini
12-19 00:03 DEBUG  CommonBackend:   Adding distro Edubuntu-i386
12-19 00:03 DEBUG  CommonBackend:   Adding distro Kubuntu-amd64
12-19 00:03 DEBUG  CommonBackend:   Adding distro Mythbuntu-i386
12-19 00:03 DEBUG  CommonBackend:   Adding distro Edubuntu-amd64
12-19 00:03 DEBUG  CommonBackend:   Adding distro Ubuntu Studio-amd64
12-19 00:03 DEBUG  CommonBackend:   Adding distro Ubuntu-amd64
12-19 00:03 DEBUG  CommonBackend:   Adding distro Lubuntu-i386
12-19 00:03 DEBUG  CommonBackend:   Adding distro Ubuntu-i386
12-19 00:03 DEBUG  CommonBackend:   Adding distro Mythbuntu-amd64
12-19 00:03 DEBUG  CommonBackend:   Adding distro Kubuntu-i386
12-19 00:03 DEBUG  CommonBackend:   Adding distro Ubuntu Studio-i386
12-19 00:03 DEBUG  CommonBackend:   Adding distro Lubuntu-amd64
12-19 00:03 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: Fetching host info...
12-19 00:03 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: registry_key=Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Wubi
12-19 00:03 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: windows version=vista
12-19 00:03 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: windows_version2=Windows 8.1
12-19 00:03 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: windows_sp=None
12-19 00:03 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: windows_build=9600
12-19 00:03 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: gmt=-5
12-19 00:03 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: country=US
12-19 00:03 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: timezone=America/New_York
12-19 00:03 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: windows_username=Tierney
12-19 00:03 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: user_full_name=Tierney
12-19 00:03 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: user_directory=C:\Users\Tierney
12-19 00:03 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: windows_language_code=1033
12-19 00:03 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: windows_language=English
12-19 00:03 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: processor_name=Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-3217U CPU @ 1.80GHz
12-19 00:03 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: bootloader=vista
12-19 00:03 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: system_drive=Drive(C: hd 232341.863281 mb free ntfs)
12-19 00:03 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: drive=Drive(C: hd 232341.863281 mb free ntfs)
12-19 00:03 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: drive=Drive(D: cd 0.0 mb free )
12-19 00:03 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: drive=Drive(E: removable 2687.60546875 mb free ntfs)
12-19 00:03 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: drive=Drive(Z: hd 99888.1953125 mb free ntfs)
12-19 00:03 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: EFI boot = True
12-19 00:03 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: uninstaller_path=None
12-19 00:03 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: previous_target_dir=None
12-19 00:03 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: previous_distro_name=None
12-19 00:03 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: keyboard_id=67699721
12-19 00:03 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: keyboard_layout=us
12-19 00:03 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: keyboard_variant=
12-19 00:03 DEBUG  CommonBackend: python locale=('en_US', 'cp1252')
12-19 00:03 DEBUG  CommonBackend: locale=en_US.UTF-8
12-19 00:03 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: total_memory_mb=3981.68359375
12-19 00:03 DEBUG  CommonBackend: Searching ISOs on USB devices
12-19 00:03 DEBUG  CommonBackend: Searching for local CDs
12-19 00:03 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether C:\Users\Tierney\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl2FE3.tmp is a valid Ubuntu CD
12-19 00:03 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain C:\Users\Tierney\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl2FE3.tmp\casper\filesystem.squashfs
12-19 00:03 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether C:\Users\Tierney\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl2FE3.tmp is a valid Ubuntu CD
12-19 00:03 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain C:\Users\Tierney\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl2FE3.tmp\casper\filesystem.squashfs
12-19 00:03 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether C:\Users\Tierney\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl2FE3.tmp is a valid Kubuntu CD
12-19 00:03 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain C:\Users\Tierney\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl2FE3.tmp\casper\filesystem.squashfs
12-19 00:03 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether C:\Users\Tierney\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl2FE3.tmp is a valid Kubuntu CD
12-19 00:03 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain C:\Users\Tierney\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl2FE3.tmp\casper\filesystem.squashfs
12-19 00:03 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether C:\Users\Tierney\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl2FE3.tmp is a valid Mythbuntu CD
12-19 00:03 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain C:\Users\Tierney\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl2FE3.tmp\casper\filesystem.squashfs
12-19 00:03 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether C:\Users\Tierney\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl2FE3.tmp is a valid Mythbuntu CD
12-19 00:03 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain C:\Users\Tierney\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl2FE3.tmp\casper\filesystem.squashfs
12-19 00:03 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether C:\Users\Tierney\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl2FE3.tmp is a valid Edubuntu CD
12-19 00:03 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain C:\Users\Tierney\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl2FE3.tmp\casper\filesystem.squashfs
12-19 00:03 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether C:\Users\Tierney\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl2FE3.tmp is a valid Edubuntu CD
12-19 00:03 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain C:\Users\Tierney\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl2FE3.tmp\casper\filesystem.squashfs
12-19 00:03 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether C:\Users\Tierney\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl2FE3.tmp is a valid Lubuntu CD
12-19 00:03 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain C:\Users\Tierney\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl2FE3.tmp\casper\filesystem.squashfs
12-19 00:03 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether C:\Users\Tierney\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl2FE3.tmp is a valid Lubuntu CD
12-19 00:03 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain C:\Users\Tierney\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl2FE3.tmp\casper\filesystem.squashfs
12-19 00:03 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether C:\Users\Tierney\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl2FE3.tmp is a valid Ubuntu Studio CD
12-19 00:03 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain C:\Users\Tierney\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl2FE3.tmp\casper\filesystem.squashfs
12-19 00:03 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether C:\Users\Tierney\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl2FE3.tmp is a valid Ubuntu Studio CD
12-19 00:03 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain C:\Users\Tierney\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl2FE3.tmp\casper\filesystem.squashfs
12-19 00:03 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether D:\ is a valid Ubuntu CD
12-19 00:03 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain D:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
12-19 00:03 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether D:\ is a valid Ubuntu CD
12-19 00:03 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain D:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
12-19 00:03 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether D:\ is a valid Kubuntu CD
12-19 00:03 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain D:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
12-19 00:03 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether D:\ is a valid Kubuntu CD
12-19 00:03 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain D:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
12-19 00:03 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether D:\ is a valid Mythbuntu CD
12-19 00:03 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain D:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
12-19 00:03 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether D:\ is a valid Mythbuntu CD
12-19 00:03 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain D:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
12-19 00:03 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether D:\ is a valid Edubuntu CD
12-19 00:03 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain D:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
12-19 00:03 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether D:\ is a valid Edubuntu CD
12-19 00:03 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain D:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
12-19 00:03 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether D:\ is a valid Lubuntu CD
12-19 00:03 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain D:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
12-19 00:03 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether D:\ is a valid Lubuntu CD
12-19 00:03 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain D:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
12-19 00:03 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether D:\ is a valid Ubuntu Studio CD
12-19 00:03 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain D:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
12-19 00:03 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether D:\ is a valid Ubuntu Studio CD
12-19 00:03 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain D:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
12-19 00:03 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether E:\ is a valid Ubuntu CD
12-19 00:03 DEBUG  Distro:   parsing info from str=Ubuntu 14.10 "Utopic Unicorn" - Release amd64 (20141022.1)
12-19 00:03 DEBUG  Distro:   parsed info={'name': 'Ubuntu', 'subversion': 'Release', 'version': '14.10', 'build': '20141022.1', 'codename': 'Utopic Unicorn', 'arch': 'amd64'}
12-19 00:03 INFO   Distro: Found a valid CD for Ubuntu: E:\
12-19 00:03 INFO   root: Running the CD menu...
12-19 00:03 DEBUG  WindowsFrontend: __init__...
12-19 00:03 DEBUG  WindowsFrontend: on_init...
12-19 00:03 INFO   WinuiPage: appname=wubi, localedir=C:\Users\Tierney\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl2FE3.tmp\translations, languages=['en_US', 'en']
12-19 00:03 INFO   WinuiPage: appname=wubi, localedir=C:\Users\Tierney\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl2FE3.tmp\translations, languages=['en_US', 'en']
12-19 00:03 INFO   root: CD menu finished
12-19 00:03 INFO   root: Running the CD boot helper...
12-19 00:03 INFO   WinuiPage: appname=wubi, localedir=C:\Users\Tierney\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl2FE3.tmp\translations, languages=['en_US', 'en']
12-19 00:03 INFO   WinuiPage: appname=wubi, localedir=C:\Users\Tierney\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl2FE3.tmp\translations, languages=['en_US', 'en']
12-19 00:03 INFO   root: CD boot helper confirmed
12-19 00:03 INFO   WinuiPage: appname=wubi, localedir=C:\Users\Tierney\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl2FE3.tmp\translations, languages=['en_US', 'en']
12-19 00:03 DEBUG  TaskList: # Running tasklist...
12-19 00:03 DEBUG  TaskList: ## Running select_target_dir...
12-19 00:03 INFO   WindowsBackend: Installing into C:\ubuntu
12-19 00:03 DEBUG  TaskList: ## Finished select_target_dir
12-19 00:03 DEBUG  TaskList: ## Running create_dir_structure...
12-19 00:03 DEBUG  CommonBackend: Creating dir C:\ubuntu
12-19 00:03 DEBUG  CommonBackend: Creating dir C:\ubuntu\disks
12-19 00:03 DEBUG  CommonBackend: Creating dir C:\ubuntu\install
12-19 00:03 DEBUG  CommonBackend: Creating dir C:\ubuntu\install\boot
12-19 00:03 DEBUG  CommonBackend: Creating dir C:\ubuntu\disks\boot
12-19 00:03 DEBUG  CommonBackend: Creating dir C:\ubuntu\disks\boot\grub
12-19 00:03 DEBUG  CommonBackend: Creating dir C:\ubuntu\install\boot\grub
12-19 00:03 DEBUG  TaskList: ## Finished create_dir_structure
12-19 00:03 DEBUG  TaskList: ## Running uncompress_target_dir...
12-19 00:03 DEBUG  TaskList: ## Finished uncompress_target_dir
12-19 00:03 DEBUG  TaskList: ## Running create_uninstaller...
12-19 00:03 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: Copying uninstaller E:\wubi.exe -> C:\ubuntu\uninstall-wubi.exe
12-19 00:03 DEBUG  registry: Setting registry key -2147483646 Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Wubi UninstallString C:\ubuntu\uninstall-wubi.exe
12-19 00:03 DEBUG  registry: Setting registry key -2147483646 Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Wubi InstallationDir C:\ubuntu
12-19 00:03 DEBUG  registry: Setting registry key -2147483646 Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Wubi DisplayName Ubuntu
12-19 00:03 DEBUG  registry: Setting registry key -2147483646 Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Wubi DisplayIcon C:\ubuntu\Ubuntu.ico
12-19 00:03 DEBUG  registry: Setting registry key -2147483646 Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Wubi DisplayVersion 14.10-rev289
12-19 00:03 DEBUG  registry: Setting registry key -2147483646 Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Wubi Publisher Ubuntu
12-19 00:03 DEBUG  registry: Setting registry key -2147483646 Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Wubi URLInfoAbout http://www.ubuntu.com
12-19 00:03 DEBUG  registry: Setting registry key -2147483646 Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Wubi HelpLink http://www.ubuntu.com/support
12-19 00:03 DEBUG  TaskList: ## Finished create_uninstaller
12-19 00:03 DEBUG  TaskList: ## Running copy_installation_files...
12-19 00:03 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: Copying C:\Users\Tierney\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl2FE3.tmp\data\custom-installation -> C:\ubuntu\install\custom-installation
12-19 00:03 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: Copying C:\Users\Tierney\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl2FE3.tmp\winboot -> C:\ubuntu\winboot
12-19 00:03 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: Copying C:\Users\Tierney\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl2FE3.tmp\data\images\Ubuntu.ico -> C:\ubuntu\Ubuntu.ico
12-19 00:03 DEBUG  TaskList: ## Finished copy_installation_files
12-19 00:03 DEBUG  TaskList: ## Running use_cd...
12-19 00:03 DEBUG  TaskList: New task copy_file
12-19 00:03 DEBUG  TaskList: ### Running copy_file...
12-19 00:07 DEBUG  TaskList: ### Finished copy_file
12-19 00:07 DEBUG  TaskList: New task check_iso
12-19 00:07 DEBUG  TaskList: ### Running check_iso...
12-19 00:07 DEBUG  CommonBackend: Checking C:\ubuntu\install\installation.iso
12-19 00:07 DEBUG  Distro:   checking Ubuntu ISO C:\ubuntu\install\installation.iso
12-19 00:07 DEBUG  WindowsBackend:   extracting .disk\info from C:\ubuntu\install\installation.iso
12-19 00:07 DEBUG  Distro:   parsing info from str=Ubuntu 14.10 "Utopic Unicorn" - Release amd64 (20141022.1)
12-19 00:07 DEBUG  Distro:   parsed info={'name': 'Ubuntu', 'subversion': 'Release', 'version': '14.10', 'build': '20141022.1', 'codename': 'Utopic Unicorn', 'arch': 'amd64'}
12-19 00:07 INFO   Distro: Found a valid iso for Ubuntu: C:\ubuntu\install\installation.iso
12-19 00:07 DEBUG  TaskList: New task get_metalink
12-19 00:07 DEBUG  TaskList: #### Running get_metalink...
12-19 00:07 DEBUG  downloader: downloading http://releases.ubuntu.com/14.10/ubuntu-14.10-desktop-amd64.metalink > C:\ubuntu\install
12-19 00:07 DEBUG  downloader: Download start filename=C:\ubuntu\install\ubuntu-14.10-desktop-amd64.metalink, url=http://releases.ubuntu.com/14.10/ubuntu-14.10-desktop-amd64.metalink, basename=ubuntu-14.10-desktop-amd64.metalink, length=40800, text=None
12-19 00:07 DEBUG  downloader: download finished (read 40800 bytes)
12-19 00:07 DEBUG  downloader: downloading http://releases.ubuntu.com/14.10/MD5SUMS-metalink > C:\ubuntu\install
12-19 00:07 DEBUG  downloader: Download start filename=C:\ubuntu\install\MD5SUMS-metalink, url=http://releases.ubuntu.com/14.10/MD5SUMS-metalink, basename=MD5SUMS-metalink, length=276, text=None
12-19 00:07 DEBUG  downloader: download finished (read 276 bytes)
12-19 00:07 DEBUG  downloader: downloading http://releases.ubuntu.com/14.10/MD5SUMS-metalink.gpg > C:\ubuntu\install
12-19 00:07 DEBUG  downloader: Download start filename=C:\ubuntu\install\MD5SUMS-metalink.gpg, url=http://releases.ubuntu.com/14.10/MD5SUMS-metalink.gpg, basename=MD5SUMS-metalink.gpg, length=198, text=None
12-19 00:07 DEBUG  downloader: download finished (read 198 bytes)
12-19 00:07 INFO   saplog: Verified a signature from ID:'46181433FBB75451'.
12-19 00:07 INFO   saplog: Checking block bindings..
12-19 00:07 INFO   saplog: Key verified successfully.
12-19 00:07 DEBUG  CommonBackend: metalink md5sums:
0e0309cebe38c8a46793e38c46f49273 *ubuntu-14.10-desktop-amd64.metalink
7453e2884e12c565ef1f9d72c5d9e524 *ubuntu-14.10-desktop-i386.metalink
e6b8d37d07290cb70102941ac0c91d7f *ubuntu-14.10-server-amd64.metalink
7dc5758bb47148f15fadad8e2f884642 *ubuntu-14.10-server-i386.metalink

12-19 00:07 ERROR  CommonBackend: The md5 of the metalink does match
12-19 00:07 ERROR  CommonBackend: Cannot authenticate the metalink file, it might be corrupt
None
12-19 00:07 DEBUG  TaskList: #### Finished get_metalink
12-19 00:07 DEBUG  TaskList: New task get_file_md5
12-19 00:07 DEBUG  TaskList: #### Running get_file_md5...
12-19 00:08 DEBUG  TaskList: #### Finished get_file_md5
12-19 00:08 ERROR  CommonBackend: Invalid md5 for ISO C:\ubuntu\install\installation.iso (08494b448aa5b1de963731c21344f803 != c5a9fed187196d55fcc94e5dde829d06)
None
12-19 00:08 DEBUG  TaskList: ### Finished check_iso
12-19 00:08 DEBUG  TaskList: ## Finished use_cd
12-19 00:08 DEBUG  TaskList: ## Running extract_kernel...
12-19 00:08 ERROR  TaskList: Could not retrieve the required installation files
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\lib\wubi\backends\common\tasklist.py", line 197, in __call__
  File "\lib\wubi\backends\common\backend.py", line 618, in extract_kernel
Exception: Could not retrieve the required installation files
12-19 00:08 DEBUG  TaskList: # Cancelling tasklist
12-19 00:08 DEBUG  TaskList: # Finished tasklist
12-19 00:08 ERROR  root: Could not retrieve the required installation files
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\lib\wubi\application.py", line 58, in run
  File "\lib\wubi\application.py", line 130, in select_task
  File "\lib\wubi\application.py", line 210, in run_cd_menu
  File "\lib\wubi\application.py", line 122, in select_task
  File "\lib\wubi\application.py", line 233, in run_cd_boot
  File "\lib\wubi\backends\common\tasklist.py", line 197, in __call__
  File "\lib\wubi\backends\common\backend.py", line 618, in extract_kernel
Exception: Could not retrieve the required installation files
```

I tried previously with essentially the same setup, but with 14.04, and got a similar error when I was trying to boot up--the typical black and white BIOS type screen, say there was a file named ubuntu (I don't remember the extension) missing.

Comment: The last supported version of wubi is 12.04. And wubi does not work on gpt partitioned drives which all pre-installed Windows 8 systems have to boot in UEFI mode. http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/7497/wubi-discussion-again-supported-here-on-ask-ubuntu-13-04-and-later/7596#7596

Answer (score 1):

Definitely a no-go using WUBI on Windows 8, don't try that (http://pad.lv/694242).

See this answer for more info than you could ever possibly want about installing on Windows 8, it's a little tricky because of gpt, UEFI, secure boot, may have to install 64-bit Ubuntu also... about 10 pages, mostly getting prepared to install, must-read:

[Installing Ubuntu Alongside a Pre-Installed Windows with UEFI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported)